# Finding the Dr. Bronowski's number

Tags: number-theory

*All credit for this problem goes to [Dr. J. Bronowski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Bronowski).*

> Find the least positive integer such that moving the leading digit to
>   the end produces a new integer one and a half times the original.

Comment: I think it should be $1176470588235294$, do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: Analogue to the question presented by "A big “smallest” number" in math.stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15598/5095

Comment: I think it's interesting in both SE, but that's what voting is there for

Comment: BTW, about the 2 closing votes for it being *off-topic*, I'd like to know how it's offtopic. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic states that questions about *Solving mathematical puzzles* **are** welcomed in math.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $10^nx_n + 10^{n-1}x_{n-1} + \cdots + 10x_1 + x_0$ denote an $n$-digit number, where $0\le x_i < 10$ is its decimal representation. The condition that we require is equivalent to the equality
$$3\left(10^nx_n + 10^{n-1}x_{n-1} + \cdots + 10x_1 + x_0\right) = 2\left(10^nx_{n-1} + 10^{n-1}x_{n-2} + \cdots + 10x_0 + x_n\right).$$
Cancelling and simplifying, this is equivalent to
$$(3\times 10^n - 2)x_n = 17\left(10^{n-1}x_{n-1} + 10^{n-2}x_{n-2} + \cdots 10x_1 + x_0\right).$$
In particular, any solution must have $17\mid (3\times 10^n - 2)$. A quick search yields $n=15$ as the first value of $n$ for which $17\mid (3\times 10^n - 2)$. In particular, we have
$$(3\times 10^n - 2)\div 17 = 176470588235294,$$
which we note is a $14$ digit number. So our equation reduces to
$$176470588235294x_{15} = 10^{14}x_{14} + 10^{13}x_{13} + \cdots 10x_1 + x_0.$$
Now this equation clearly has a solution (in fact it has a family of solutions, but we only care about the smallest) by taking $x_{15} = 1$ and by taking $x_{15-i}$ as the $i$th digit of $176470588235294$.

This gives us the smallest solution as $1176470588235294$, which  user109899 also gives in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

If there is such a number, it has the form $a\cdot10^n+b$, where $1\le a\le9$ is a digit and $b\lt10^n$.  The modified number is $10b+a$, so

$$10b+a={3\over2}(a\cdot10^n+b)\iff 20b+2a=3a\cdot10^n+3b\iff17b=a(3\cdot10^n-2)$$

Since $17$ is prime, the last equation is satisfied if and only it divides $3\cdot10^n-2$ for some $n$, which is to say (noting that $6\cdot3\equiv1$ mod $17$), if and only if $10^n\equiv12$ mod $17$ for some $n$.

It turns out there is such an $n$.  You can prove this without explicitly finding the $n$ by noting that $10^2\equiv-2$ mod $17$, so $10^4\equiv 4$ mod $17$, so $10^8\equiv-1$ mod $17$, which imply $10$ is a primitive root in the cyclic group of units mod $17$, which has order $16$.

As it happens, knowing that $10$ is a primitive root and observing that $10\cdot12=120\equiv1$ mod $17$ shows that $n=15$ is the smallest such $n$.

Finally, observe that $b=(3\cdot10^n-2)/17\lt10^n$, so

$$1\cdot10^n+{3\cdot10^n-2\over17}$$

will be the appropriate number, provided you plug in $n=15$.

(Remark:  I see that EuYu posted essentially the same answer while I was composing mine.  The only substantial difference is how we each went about finding $n=15$ for the smallest solution.)

Comment: I really like this solution, way different than the other one given.

Comment: I acknowledge both answers as great and time here is not a good way to choose, since clearly you begun writing your answer before he posted his. Still I can only choose one best answer so I ended up with the one that feels (at least to me) more intuitive and easy to extrapolate for similar games.